# Why ${S_{n-1}}$ is not a subgroup of ${S_n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

I know that in general this is not true. Also, I know that subgroups of index n of ${S_n}$ are isomorphic to ${S_{n-1}}$ but why they are not subgroups? For example, why ${S_6}$ is not a subgroup of ${S_7}$? We have closure, existence of inverses and unit element. What do I miss here?
Thanx

Comment: You are missing that $S_6 \not \subset S_7$, for instance.

Comment: $S_6$ can be identified with a subgroup of $S_7$ via an injective homomorphism, so it can make sense to view it as a subgroup. However, it fails the basic test of not being a subset.

Comment: But every element in ${S_6}$ is also in ${S_7}$. So why it is not a subset?

Comment: Elements of S_6 and elements of S_7 are functions with different domains and ranges. Hence one is not a subset of the other.

Comment: But I can look at ${S_6}$ as function that always takes 7 to 7. So they both will have the same range.

Comment: Just because you can *view* a group as a subgroup of another (i.e., via an isomorphism with the subgroup) doesn't mean that it really *is* a subgrorup.

Comment: @AlexProvost, It is really confusing. Do you have any example beside the symmetric groups?

Comment: Another example: $\mathbb R$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ although it is isomorphic to the subset $\mathbb R\times\{0\}$ of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: "But I can look at [an element of] $S_6$ as a function that always takes $7$ to $7$." True, but there's a big difference between "I can look at an [X] as a [Y]" and "An [X] is a [Y]."

Comment: Actually $S_n$ is Permutation group on $n$ things. It is independent on natural number $1$ to $n$ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you can *view* a group as a subgroup of another (i.e., via an isomorphism with the subgroup) doesn't mean that it really *is* a subgroup.

For a perhaps more enlightening example, consider $\mathbb{Z}/2$. This is not a subset of $\mathbb{Z}/4$ in the strict sense of the term, but if we see the former as $\{0,1\}$ and the latter as $\{0,1,2,3\}$, it is. However, this doesn't exhibit $\mathbb{Z}/2$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/4$. On the other hand, one *can* see $\mathbb{Z}/2$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/4$ by viewing the former as $\{0,2\}$ instead of $\{0,1\}$. So, knowing this, would you say that $\mathbb{Z}/2$ *is* without a shadow of a doubt a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/4$?

Comment: But in your example we have a different group operation. ${\mathbb{Z}/2 }$ has addition ${(mod2)}$ and ${\mathbb{Z}/4}$ has addition ${(mod4)}$. In case of symmetric groups we have the same group operation. In my example, if the permutations would be declared as ${S_6}$ ${\bigcup 7\rightarrow 7}$ would it be a subgroup of ${S_7}$?

Comment: No, your symmetric groups also have distinct operations (that's the point). One is a binary operation $S_6 \times S_6 \to S_6$, and the other is a binary operation $S_7 \times S_7 \to S_7$.

Comment: Thanks. I think I do understand now.